# How to export data when the fieldnames are stored in one table and the data in another

Tags: mysql, export

I have two tables:

Table *field* stores data of form field names (e. g.: Name, Age, Email each as one Dataset):

```
id | formName | filedName
1  | 1        | name
2  | 1        | age
3  | 2        | name
4  | 2        | age
```

Table *data* stores data for each field:

```
id | fieldName | userID |data
1  | 1         | 1      |Peter
2  | 1         | 2      |Steve
3  | 2         | 1      |24
4  | 2         | 2      |34
```

I want to export the data as CSV from phpMyAdmin in a way that gives me the data from *field* as column names and the *data* from data as the specific value. 
It should look something like this:

```
name  | age
Peter | 24
Steve | 34
```

What is the query for that?
I know it is possible since I already did this a while back, cannot remember the syntax though.

Comment: Do you have any other fields to group by? I mean, how can we assume that Peter has a age of 24?

Comment: good point! That's just a simplified example since the original tables are much more complex, but i just need a starting point to figure that problem out
The original table as a userID as well since the field-names are userprofile with custom userfield from a CMS

Comment: Now we can group by userID. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only name and age then you can get your desired results from your data_table only otherwise you can also join field table also. Please try below query and let me know if you think that you need some thing else.

```
select a.data as 'Name',b.data as 'Age' 
from (select userid,data from tablename where fieldname=1) a 
join (select userid,data from tablename where fieldname=2) b 
on a.userid=b.userid;
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work 100%, but i can figure out the rest and will post my final solution here for others to see ;)

Comment: if you share what is issue then I can help you.

Comment: actually your code is (almost) correct: for this example i just need a third table for the user-data, which i forgot for my example but have in reality.

Everything works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: This will not get OP what he is after. See the result of [**your query**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b539/6).

Comment: You are right, there is one issue: instead of a Join the result has to be grouped by the userid. Therefore, the If-statement have to be cancated by using GROUP_CONCAT

But that works finde for me!

Comment: @RagingBull thanks now i have changed my query, it should work perfactly.

Comment: That works. Removed my down vote. In my opinion, you should not go with inner queries. It lacks performance.

Comment: @RagingBull: As functions and group by also decrease performance so some time inner queries can give better results and some time group by and function etc..it will totally depend on amount of data tables have..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply using `MAX` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName=1 THEN data END) as name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName=2 THEN data END) as age
FROM TableName
GROUP BY userID
```

Result:

```
NAME    AGE
Peter   24
Steve   34
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b539/3).

Comment: I didn't try your query since i didn't see this before i tried the other one. But thank you very much for your support.